# Ломается верстка на больших мониторах

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - на главной странице сайта очень мало контента, и при ёё отображении на больших мониторах часть экрана пустует. У заказчика монитор 2К с разрешением 2560х1440. Как поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие классы и с какими свойствами надо прописать?

http://mimi.webstars.com.ua/

Comment: вы напишите, как вы хотите, чтобы было?

Comment: На ретине страшновато смотрится, особенно красная надпись на чёрном квадрате уж больно мыльная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте этих стилей:

```
.pageContant {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Чёт не помогло. + footer уезжает вверх при уменьшении экрана

Answer (score 2):

```
.container {
    width: 73%;
}
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.bl_fullBlock {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

в сss код блока который вам нужно растянуть по всей высоте добавьте:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

> имнимальная высота блока по всей высоте екрана

можно также отнимать нужное вам количество пикселей через ф-цию calc:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

> имнимальная высота блока по всей высоте екрана минус сто пикселей